# How do I make a card flip using TweenLite?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, gsap

I have been trying to implement this http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=42802 using two 200/100 sprites but the results are totally unexpected.

The card flies from the start, towards the right, then comes back to the start and halfway it flips. While the effect itself looks nice, the problem is with rotatingY property and z property.

I tried making a simple sprite rotating with some perspective and the anchor point seems to NOT be the 0,0 origin. From what I read it has something to do with the parent but I can't put my finger on it.

Thus my issue: How do I make a card flip using TweenLite? It would suffice using TweenLite to flip a sprite, on its Y axis, with the focal point at the center of the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092259/as3-spin-text-around-center/18096811#18096811)

but if its an strange perspective you are seeing [maybe this could help you out](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/pp/)

And if you need to adjust positioning, you can always create a new Sprite() and throw what you want in there center it in the new sprite, and tween lite the new sprite =]

Answer (score -1):

`TweenLite.to(myTarget, 3, {rotationX:180})`