# AS3 spin text around center?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, text, flex4

I am trying to get an effect like this:
http://www.welcomeanimations.com/welcome_animated_gifs_rotating_sign_orange_chrome_k_1.htm

I have tried all sorts of things:

- Matrix translation/rotation - spins the text around the 'Z' axis, instead of 'Y'
- Adding TextField to a sprite, and Sprite.rotationY++: reg. point is upper left corner
- Adding to MovieClip - same as above (an article said MovieClip's reg. point was centered).

This should be trivial?!?! Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: You might need to use a library like Papervision3D if you want realistic 3D objects like that.

Comment: If you want realistic, 3D rotation like that example you showed, Marty's right; you'll have to use a library for that sort of stuff. You should specify whether you want to do it with a 3D object or a 2D image.

Comment: Already using Away3D ;^) - but puggsoy is right, I should have specified I am just trying to rotate a simple TextField on a 2D Sprite. (for the curious, it's for a game menu - the Away3D stuff is for the game itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to remember, Display objects scale and rotate around their local coordinate  system.  so when you put a textfield in a sprite, you need to center it in that sprite's coordinate  system. And doing that for textfields is annoying because their width/height isn't always accurate but there is trick for that: [get visual bounds](https://gist.github.com/rafaelrinaldi/637497), but normally you can take half of somethings width and height

I've created [a prototype for you on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/oTmL) so you can see the solution working in action.  Click on the blue square to see how the local coordinate system messes with the rotation

Finally as you use thing you might find things not rotating in 3D space quite right, [this should be able to fix that.](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/pp/)

Comment: I found my error - when adding my text field to the container sprite, I wasn't properly centering it; I had: tf.x = -(tf.width), instead of tf.x = -(tf.width * 0.5). D'oh!